# Is there a way to do subscripts/superscripts in Matplotlib without TeX?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am finding that TeX messes with my fonts, the alignment of my subplot yaxis labels, etc and I feel like there must be an easier way to get subcripts and superscripts in plot labels. Help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `\mathregular{whatever}` in your expression.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.2, 0.7, 'No mathtex')
ax.text(0.2, 0.5, 'This superscript $is^{in}$ italics')
ax.text(0.2, 0.3, 'While this $\mathregular{is^{really}}$ the same font')
plt.show()
```

[image]

See http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way you can use TeX-like rendering without the mathtext engine (or using LaTeX directly).  However if your problems are really about text alignment, maybe the text alignment kwargs `horizontalalignment`, `verticalalignment`, and `multialignment` will help?

Docs here: http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html